# How to query a Google Spreadsheet using toDate when there are only empty values in the selected column

Tags: google-visualization

The column I want to query using toDate contains only empty values, the query fails it does not execute.

Query: select * where toDate(A) >= '2016-01-01'.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19olM1pEF5qQvvKhwSH3d_X4w2DVfOWDwDtZKNFlMY3w/edit#gid=0

What should I do?

Note: The query works fine even if there is a single entry in the given column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about `toDate`...

But to convert a value to a date, simply prefix the value with the word 'date'.

i.e. --> `date '2016-01-01'`

See following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19olM1pEF5qQvvKhwSH3d_X4w2DVfOWDwDtZKNFlMY3w/edit#gid=0'
  );

  query.setQuery("select * where A >= date '2016-01-01'");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  if (data.getNumberOfRows() === 0) {
    data.setColumnLabel(0, 'Date');
    data.setColumnLabel(1, 'Goal');
    data.addRow([null, 'Nothing found']);
  }

  var visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  visualization.draw(data, {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But if my column is of dateTime format and i just want to compare date. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: glad to help but I don't follow the question -- compare date column to what?

Comment: Suppose my column 'A' contains the value  '2016-03-29T18:31:01.000Z ' and i want to execute a query like this :  select * A >= date '2016-03-29'