# Query CSV file with google visualization query

Tags: csv, google-visualization

I am trying to query a csv file with google visualization query but every time I am getting 'Error in query: 404 file not found' error and am not able to resolve it.

any pointers / suggestions / thought would be highly appreciated.

Note - the csv file exists on my local server and if click on link http://localhost:35802/test.csv it downloaded the file for me

here is my code --

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        //var opts = { sendMethod: 'auto' };
        // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('csv?url=http://localhost:35802/test.csv');

        // Optional request to return only column C and the sum of column B, grouped by C members.
        query.setQuery('select * ');

        // Send the query with a callback function.
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) 
    {
        if (response.isError()) 
        {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        //alert(response);
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });

    }
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

here is my csv file content -- 
    A,B,C
    1,2,3
    4,5,6

Comment: why `csv?url=`? not just `'http://localhost:35802/test.csv'` -- see [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries-stealth#reading-csv-files)?

Comment: @WhiteHat -- Thanks for responding to my question.... I tried using that but nothing happen...didn't get any error though. On checking the network trace,  I see that request has been sent and response is also received but response doesn't have any data.....

Comment: maybe check `response.hasWarning()` and `response.getReasons()` -- [QueryResponse Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#QueryResponse)

Comment: @WhiteHat --  I checked response.hasWarning() and response.getReasons() but no luck. I also applied a break point in the beginning of handleQueryResponse() but breakpoint never got a hit. As I mentioned that in the network trace I am receiving a response but that does not contain any data...If its not too much to ask can you try to create a working code and share it with me...that would be of great help!!

Comment: I have created a fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/491fmv4p/4/....just in case some one want to try their hands....In this fiddle I am using a csv file from google..I don't know how I can upload a csv file to fiddle...Also with this fiddle I am receiving Request Time out Error....may be because I am on a different domain then google and trying to access csv file on google domain....

Comment: @WhiteHat --- you forget the link..

Comment: sorry, [here's a working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36433942/5090771) but it's not csv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @WhiteHat for the pointers.. finally I got it working...:)
the culprit was the google library that I was loading.

Initially I was loading -- 
`<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`
which was not working for me...

I was able to run my code by changing this library to 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

for anyone who needs a working sample here it is  -- 
please change the path to csv file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        //        var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/gstatic/charts/static/data.csv',
        //          { csvColumns: ['string', 'number'], csvHasHeader: true });
        var opt = { sendMethod: 'xhr' }; //{ csvColumns: ['string', 'number'], csvHasHeader: true, sendMethod: auto });
        //var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://local:6572/data.csv', opt);
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://localhost:6572/data.csv');
        query.setQuery('select *');
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
                    response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('csv'));
        chart.draw(data, { legend: { position: 'none'} });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="csv" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```